# How to call a sql function from PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using `Spring` with `PreparedStatement`, and want to  prepare the sql to use a function of the db. But the following does not work:

```
String sql = "SELECT somefunct(?,?)";
```

When I run it with the preparedstatement, I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT somefunct(?,?)]; Batch-Eintrag 0 SELECT somefunct('XX','XX') wurde abgebrochen.  Rufen Sie 'getNextException' auf, um die Ursache zu erfahren.; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch-Eintrag 0 SELECT somefunct('XX','XX') wurde abgebrochen.  Rufen Sie 'getNextException' auf, um die Ursache zu erfahren.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.scan(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:578)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.access$900(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:458)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:320)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:420)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:677)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:695)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch-Eintrag 0 SELECT somefunct('X','test') wurde abgebrochen.  Rufen Sie 'getNextException' auf, um die Ursache zu erfahren.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2743)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2692)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleResultRows(QueryExecutorImpl.java:439)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1853)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2892)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `CallableStatement` instead? You may want to check JDBC Specification. It contains examples on how to execute stored functions/procedures. There is an entire chapter (13) on callable statements. Although it would look like what you did should work.

Comment: Can you please change your locale to en_US and run that again, so that we get an error message we can read?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: no, in Postgres you don't need a `CallableStatement` because it is indeed a function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: `java.sql.BatchUpdateException` seems to indicate that you are running this as a batched statement (`PreparedStatement.addBatch()` and `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()`) I don't think this is supported. What happens when you don't use batching?

Comment: Oh OK. In that case, chances are the function is indeed being invoked but it is failing during the execution of it. The stack trace seems to be in another language other than English and I dot understand the message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm running this in the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` context, which automatically calls `addBatch()`. Probably I could not change this...

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
 String callSQL = "{ ? = call db_function(?) }";

 CallableStatement statement = pConnection.prepareCall(callSQL);

 statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
 statement.setString(2, param);

 statement.execute();

 String result = statement.getString(1);
```

Where `pConnection` is `java.sql.Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring and as such have access to Spring JDBC, you can use the class `StoredProcedure` as [described in their documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure). We have used a similar approach to test the generation function of our oracle full-text.

```java
public class SomeFunct extends StoredProcedure {

    private static final String SQL = "somefunct";

    public SomeFunct(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setFunction(true);
        setSql(SQL);
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("input", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("input-2", Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();
    }

    public String execute(String input, String input2) {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("input", input);
        parameters.put("input-2", input2);
        Map<String, Object> results = execute(parameters);
        // if the name of the result is not known, 
        // you may iterate over the entries of the map
        String result = (String) results.get("name-of-result");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make use of that in a `JdbcBatchItemWriter`?

Comment: @membersound Would you add more code in your question, how you employ the JdbcBatchItemWriter?